# How to setup a shower timer to actually turn off the water?

Tags: shower, timer

My kids take very long showers and I can't always be there to rush them out.
Is there a way to have a timer start once the shower starts and actively stop the water after 10-15 minutes?

I've looked around and not been able to find anything that really does this.
At my local HD, the sales person just said "tell your kids to get out of the shower.", thanks a lot!

Comment: "Do you want to shut off the water entirely, or just the hot water?" he asked, with an evil glint in his eyes...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This device may help. It is [The Shower Manager](http://www.showermanager.com/conservation-store/shower-timer-home.shtml)